# Ordering by a related classes created_at in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a model User with a related class (User has_many Posts, Post belongs_to User).  I want to display Users in a list, with those who have posted most recently at the top.  So basically I want to order the List of Users by the created_at date of their last post.  How is the best way to query this in Rails 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  has_one :last_post, :order => 'created_at DESC', :class_name => "Post"

  scope :sort_by_last_post_desc, :include => :last_post, :order => ('posts.created_at DESC')
end
```

NOTE: not tested

Answer (score 2):

I think I would just do this by pulling the Posts, ordering by created_at and doing a group by on the user_id.